# Magento: Setting a node in the config xml data from code?

Tags: magento, routes

I configured a router, like this:

```
<rewrite>
   <My_Module>
        <from><![CDATA[#^/computer/configuration/#]]></from>
        <to>/config/configuration/</to>
        <complete>1</complete>
    </My_Module>
</rewrite>
```

This works, whenever I access a URL looking like */computer/configuration/*, it routes to */config/configuration/*. What I want, is to change this behaviour in the code. So, in my code, I am getting the from like this:

```
$from = (string) Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/rewrite/My_Module/from');
```

This works, what I get back is *#^/computer/configuration/#*. Now I try to change the from:

```
$from = '#^/somethingelse/configuration/#';
Mage::getConfig()->setNode('global/rewrite/My_Module/from', $from);
Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig();

// This returns me the new value (#^/somethingelse/configuration/#)
$from = (string) Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/rewrite/My_Module/from');
```

But the routing does not work, it gives me the 404 not found page. It seems, the value I set is not really saved. Did I forget something in my code?

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: The signature of saveConfig is `function saveConfig($path, $value, $scope = 'default', $scopeId = 0)`. Try `Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('global/rewrite/My_Module/from', $from);`

Comment: Right, I tried:

`Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('global/rewrite/My_Module/from', $from);` 

This does not work either. After that, I get the value again in Mage_Cms_Controller_Router in the match function and its still /computer/configuration/.

Comment: Where are you calling this code?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the configuration needs to be re-initialized after it is saved. Try this:

```
Mage::app()->getConfig()->reinit();
```

...and you may also need this:

```
Mage::app()->reinitStores();
```